# how do i get the Comment-ID with the comment_post_form

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

I´m searching for a way to hook into `comment_post_form` and `update_comment_meta`, if something, but i can´t figure out how to get the comment-ID.

The function is in the functions.php

```
function add_comment_drawing() {

    $drawingsave = $_POST['drawinginput'];
    if ($drawingsave == 'Das Bild wird gespeichert'){
    update_comment_meta(  $comment->ID, 'drawingurl', 'Brad' );
    }


 }
add_action('comment_post', 'add_comment_drawing');
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Comment Actions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Comment.2C_Ping.2C_and_Trackback_Actions):

> comment_post
>   Runs just after a comment is saved in the database. **Action function arguments: comment ID, approval status ("spam", or 0/1 for disapproved/approved)**.

```
function add_comment_drawing($comment_id){
    $drawingsave = isset($_POST['drawinginput']) ? $_POST['drawinginput'] : false;
    if($drawingsave == 'Das Bild wird gespeichert'){
        update_comment_meta($comment_id, 'drawingurl', 'Brad' );
    }
}
add_action('comment_post', 'add_comment_drawing', 10, 1);
```

Comment: thanks, will try! But what means the 10 and 1/2 in the action hook?

Comment: 10 is the priority of the action, meaning the lower the number is, the earlier the execution. The 1 defines how many arguments you want to pass to the callback. In this case, since you only needed the comment ID (which incidentally is the first argument passed to the callback), I explicitly provided the 1 for clarity's sake. 1 is actually the default, so it's not actually required in this specific instance. [More on add_action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the arguments in your function.

```
function add_comment_drawing( $comment_id, $approval_status ) {

    $drawingsave = $_POST['drawinginput'];
    if ($drawingsave == 'Das Bild wird gespeichert'){
        update_comment_meta(  $comment_id, 'drawingurl', 'Brad' );
    }
}
add_action( 'comment_post', 'add_comment_drawing', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

***" i can´t figure out how to get the comment-ID"***

- **add_action**: adds an action to the queue
- **do_action**: somewhere in the code where the queued actions are executed (Find it!)

in this case: /wp-includes/comment.php line 1811.

about 10 lines above you see:

```
$comment_ID = wp_insert_comment($commentdata);
    if ( ! $comment_ID ) {
        return false;
    }
```

So your comment_ID is what is provided BY the "add_action" (in this case by the wp_insert_comment method/function; so that you can use it in your function, not the other way around. E.g. log the comment_ID to a file or something.

***"How does add_action work / parameters ? "***

Open /wp-includes/plugin.php, search for "add_action" and around line 400 you see:

```
**
 * Hooks a function on to a specific action.
 *
 * Actions are the hooks that the WordPress core launches at specific points
 * during execution, or when specific events occur. Plugins can specify that
 * one or more of its PHP functions are executed at these points, using the
 * Action API.
 *
 * @uses add_filter() Adds an action. Parameter list and functionality are the same.
 *
 * @since 1.2.0
 *
 * @param string $tag The name of the action to which the $function_to_add is hooked.
 * @param callback $function_to_add The name of the function you wish to be called.
 * @param int $priority optional. Used to specify the order in which the functions associated with a particular action are executed (default: 10). Lower numbers correspond with earlier execution, and functions with the same priority are executed in the order in which they were added to the action.
 * @param int $accepted_args optional. The number of arguments the function accept (default 1).
 */
function add_action($tag, $function_to_add, $priority = 10, $accepted_args = 1) {
    return add_filter($tag, $function_to_add, $priority, $accepted_args);
}
```

***"How does do _action work / parameters ? "***

idem. Look in wp-includes/plugin.php and look around line 427:

```
/**
 * Execute functions hooked on a specific action hook.
 *
 * This function invokes all functions attached to action hook $tag. It is
 * possible to create new action hooks by simply calling this function,
 * specifying the name of the new hook using the <tt>$tag</tt> parameter.
 *
 * You can pass extra arguments to the hooks, much like you can with
 * apply_filters().
 *
 * @see apply_filters() This function works similar with the exception that
 * nothing is returned and only the functions or methods are called.
 *
 * @since 1.2.0
 *
 * @global array $wp_filter Stores all of the filters
 * @global array $wp_actions Increments the amount of times action was triggered.
 *
 * @param string $tag The name of the action to be executed.
 * @param mixed $arg,... Optional additional arguments which are passed on to the functions hooked to the action.
 * @return null Will return null if $tag does not exist in $wp_filter array
 */
function do_action($tag, $arg = '') {
    global $wp_filter, $wp_actions, $merged_filters, $wp_current_filter;

    if ( ! isset($wp_actions[$tag]) )
        $wp_actions[$tag] = 1;
    else
        ++$wp_actions[$tag];

    // Do 'all' actions first
    if ( isset($wp_filter['all']) ) {
        $wp_current_filter[] = $tag;
        $all_args = func_get_args();
        _wp_call_all_hook($all_args);
    }

    if ( !isset($wp_filter[$tag]) ) {
        if ( isset($wp_filter['all']) )
            array_pop($wp_current_filter);
        return;
    }

    if ( !isset($wp_filter['all']) )
        $wp_current_filter[] = $tag;

    $args = array();
    if ( is_array($arg) && 1 == count($arg) && isset($arg[0]) && is_object($arg[0]) ) // array(&$this)
        $args[] =& $arg[0];
    else
        $args[] = $arg;
    for ( $a = 2; $a < func_num_args(); $a++ )
        $args[] = func_get_arg($a);

    // Sort
    if ( !isset( $merged_filters[ $tag ] ) ) {
        ksort($wp_filter[$tag]);
        $merged_filters[ $tag ] = true;
    }

    reset( $wp_filter[ $tag ] );

    do {
        foreach ( (array) current($wp_filter[$tag]) as $the_ )
            if ( !is_null($the_['function']) )
                call_user_func_array($the_['function'], array_slice($args, 0, (int) $the_['accepted_args']));

    } while ( next($wp_filter[$tag]) !== false );

    array_pop($wp_current_filter);
}
```

So the main "trick" around add_action / do_action / filter is **call_user_func_array()** : http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php , once you understand that function, you understand what these functions in WP do.

***"How does do _???? work "***

So in general : just look at the source code of WordPress (that is the advantage its opensource)

another tip is to use an IDE, something like Eclipse or Netbeans: they can show you a lot of info in the IDE, and on top of that: during "runtime" you get a lot of info through the debugger.